# Trigger click in Typescript - Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to trigger a click event on a HTML element in Typescript/Reactjs.

```
let element: Element = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
element.click();
```

The code above does work. But I'm getting a Typescript error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/App.tsx:124:17
TS2339: Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

So what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Use the type **[HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)** instead of **[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)**. HTMLElement inherits from Element. And in the documentation you can find that `click` function is defined in the HTMLElement.

Cast your element into the HTMLElement via

```
let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0] as HTMLElement;
element.click();
```

Comment: or even `HTMLButtonElement` if you know it's a `<button/>`

Comment: Nope: ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/Game.tsx:123:13
TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
Property 'accessKey' is missing in type 'Element'.

Comment: Use cast operator `document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0] as HTMLElement`

Comment: Thanks that was it! Didn't know that I could cast types like that. Gives me the Java feeling :o)

Comment: typescript is such garbage sometimes

Answer (score 29):

Correct (type safe) way is:

```js
if (element instanceof HTMLElement) {
  element.click();
}
```

You shouldn't use forced casts (as suggested by other answers) unless you *really* need them.

Answer (score 18):

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.ant-table-row-expand-icon')
  .forEach(node => node.click())
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Comment: Only way it worked!

Comment: Yep. Nothing worked except this.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ref` to access DOM.

```
<button  ref={button => this.buttonElement = button} />
In your event handler:

this.buttonElement.click();// trigger click event
```

Or,Create HtmlEvents and attach to dom element.

```
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("click", true, true);
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: initEvent is not standard any more.

Answer (score 4):

Use Like this

```
(<HTMLElement>document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0]).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

had a similar issue while scripting using Puppeteer , the following helped to resolve the type: `srcTracker:HTMLElement`

`page.$eval(this.selectorElement,(srcTracker:HTMLElement) => srcTracker.click());`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-property-click-not-exist-type-element#:%7E:text=If%20you%20used%20the%20document.getElementsByClassName%20method%2C%20type%20the%20collection%20as%20HTMLCollectionOf%3CHTMLElement%3E.), also

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName(
  "btn"
) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
```