# How do you programatically fire a click event on a select field in an angular app?

Tags: angular

I have styled a select field with a custom dropdown icon using this css on the select:

```
appearance: none;       /* remove default arrow */
```

And then using an absolutely positioned icon.

Now I want that icon when clicked to trigger the click event on the select field. I have tried using ViewChild to get the select element ref and trigger a click on it's nativeElement property but nothing happens.

```
@ViewChild('customInput') input: ElementRef;
click() {
  const ele = this.input.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  ele.click();
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

I have also tried template references:

```
<select #customInput>

<div class="arrow" (click)="customInput.click()"></div>
```

EDIT:

it is also worth noting that both approaches using `.focus()` instead does focus the element, but does not cause the dropdown list to appear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204003/trigger-click-in-typescript-property-click-does-not-exist-on-type-element

Comment: @NnN that posts deals with a typescript compilation error. The object is the same whether I infer it as Element or HtmlElement since after compilation that distinction does not exist. Therefore this is not the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list You cant get js to open a select dropdown...

Comment: @Craig can you tell about your problem in more clear way... we are confused what exactly you want to acheive

Comment: And to be sure we talk about the same thing, consider providing a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @programoholic I am attempting to get the select options to display programatically by clicking another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got there in the end.

It turns out that javaScript is unable to make a select field open in a normal way and so I rethought the problem and ended up using a background image positioned where the custom styled arrow would be. This is obviously slower as before I was using a material icon so it was just a font, now it is an image that it has to render - but the performance hit is so small i dont think it matters.

since the dropdown icon is now just a background image it is part of the select so when you click it you really click the select itself and that causes it to open correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Your  HTML

```
 <select #customInput (click)="SelectClick()">
   <option value="1">Option</option>
 </select>
 <div class="arrow" (click)="click()">Click Here</div>
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('customInput') input: ElementRef;
click() {
  alert('Div click');
  const ele = this.input.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  ele.click();
 }
 SelectClick()
 {
  alert("Select Click");
 }
```

Comment: That caused selectclick to run :0

Comment: im very confused about this now.

Answer (score 0):

Craig, Here is a sample guide how you can open a select box programatically :

```js
let openStatus = false;

function openSelect(){
openStatus = !openStatus;
var element = document.getElementById('names');
if(openStatus){
element.size = element.length;  
 } 
 else {
 element.size = 1;   
  }
}

function handleChange(){
 alert('element slected ... closed');
 openSelect();
 }
```

```html
<select id="names" onchange="handleChange()">
    <option>Foso</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
</select>


<button onClick="openSelect()"> open Select </button>
```

When you click on the button it opens the select box. and when you click again on the button or select any element , the select box gets closed. 
I have used raw html and JS to explain the workaround . You can implement the same technique in angular too. 
Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: This is a great answer however there are some problems with this approach that makes it not usable for me:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select claims that browser support is patchy

2. this opens the select in a very strange way - the options are contained within the select.

Thank you for the answer though it was very interesting.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp

w3schools also claims issues with size 2 and size 3 on some browsers however I dont know it that is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mat-select from Material so just replace the below a line

`const ele = this.input.nativeElement as HTMLElement;`

with

`const ele = this.input['trigger'].nativeElement as HTMLElement;`