# Angular Accordion accessibility issues

Tags: html, angular, accessibility

have an issue with the expansion of the accordion containing a list of items using a keyboard.

There is a complication in that all the accordion's data is being populated from an API, so a lot of the solutions that I had seen are hardcoded. For example, using the information found in the article below didn't work as the unique values are hard coded:

https://www.hassellinclusion.com/blog/accessible-accordion-pattern/

I've added in a lot of the appropriate ARIA labels and navigating via tab around it works well as does the screen reader, but I can't get the accordion to expand.

I tried to talking it from another angle by getting the enter button to be interpreted as a click on the element to expand the accordion but got completely lost trying to do such a thing in Angular as inserting Vanilla JS is not as straight forward as it would seem.

Here is the code, it's spread over three components so I've compiled into one and removed some styling classes for legibility:

```
  <div tabindex="0" (keydown.enter)="myFunction()" role="button">
    <h2 tabindex="0">
      <img>
      <i tabindex="0"></i>{{ organiser.name }}
    </h2>

    //this component displays the selected item. the accessibility on this works fine
<app-selected-area role="region">
    </app-selected-area>

  </div>
  <div class="content">

//this component displays the items that can be selected

        <app-skill-item class="item">
    <div tabindex="0" role="button">
      <h3>{{ skill.name }}</h3>

      <button *ngIf="updateable && isSelected()" (click)="select()">
        Remove 
        <span class="screen-reader-only">
          {{ skill.name }}
        </span>
        skill
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="updateable && !isSelected()" (click)="select()" tabindex="0">
        Add 
        <span class="screen-reader-only">
          {{ skill.name }}
        </span>
        skill
      </button>

   </app-skill-item>
  </div>
```

Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the answer for this in the follow question/thread:
[Trigger click in Typescript - Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204003/trigger-click-in-typescript-property-click-does-not-exist-on-type-element)

```
let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0] as HTMLElement;
element.click();
```

this was the following code that let me manipulate the accordion via the enter key as a click